# Get a hard coded jquery selector from an array and hide it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I get each hard coded selector from the array and hide it using the jQuery hide() method?

```
function hideAllExcept(except) {
//Create an array to contain all of the sub navigation elements
var sub_navigation = new Array();
//Get each sub ul element of the main ul and push it to the previously created array
    $('#navigation_sub ul').each(function(index, element) {
        sub_navigation.push('$("#' +this.id+'")');
    });


var x  = sub_navigation.length;


for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    $(sub_navigation).each(function(index, element) {
        $(sub_navigation)[0].hide();            
        alert(element);
        alert(this);  
        this.hide();
    })

}
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to work with selectors when you've already got the elements themselves? Much of this code does not make sense to me. Why are you using a hardcoded index (`$(sub_navigation)[0]`) in the `.each()`? Why does this code ignore the `except` parameter?

Comment: Why are you storing javascript as a string rather that just storing the selector string?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to save the IDs, just cache the jQuery object that contains those elements.

```
var $subnav = $('#navigation_sub ul');

...

$subnav.hide();
```

I note that you haven't actually used your `except` parameter.  If it's a legal selector you can just do:

```
$subnav.not(except).hide();
```

which could make your entire function just this:

```
function hideAllExcept(except) {
    $subnav.not(except).hide();
    $(except).show();  // assuming that you want to make this one visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
sub_navigation.push('$("#' +this.id+'")');
```

To this:

```
sub_navigation.push("#" +this.id);
```

And this:

```
$(sub_navigation)[0].hide();
```

To this:

```
$(element).hide();
```

And remove the unneeded for loop because you are looping with `.each`.

But there are much better ways to handle this. Like caching the jQuery object as @Alnitak suggested

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish but this hardcodes the selectors into an array and then hides each of the elements.

```
    // hardcode selectors
    var subnav_elements = ["ul#subnav1", "ul#subnav2", "ul#subnav3"];

    // for each subnav element, hide it!
    $(subnav_elements).each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Comment: `jQuery(selector_array)` isn't legal, unless you call `.toString()` on the array first to convert it into a comma separated list.  And there's no need for the `.each` - the `.hide()` call will happily iterate over the whole collection.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  I know what I was thinking when I wrote this, but I don't know why I was thinking that way. Thanks!

Comment: You _can_ pass an array of elements, just not an array of selectors.